# Issues other than speed of execution in calling Java code from Jython or Scala

Tags: java, scala, scalability, jython, neo4j

I am using neo4j as backend in my project.
For frontend,I dont want to do it in java as I am feeling too restricted in it.
I am consider 2 options which are
a) Use Jython/Django as I can call my java code in it. So that I can simply provide a good API of my database code and call it.
b) Use Scala/Lift as do same as mentioned in above.

The only downside to this which I can think of now is it may be slow as calling one language from another and this can be a factor in scalability. 
I would like advise on what other issues can be there which  can affect my project or this slowness alone can affect a lot?
If too many then I would have to move to java only as neo4j suits perfectly to the project

P.S I am not inclined to any language.Ready to do it in any and I am not opting for Java not because I dont like but the thing is I am not sure about it because of cost factors and learning curve.Any advise on that would be cool.

Comment: What do you mean with "frontend"? Is there any networking involvbed or is this a monolithic app with neo4j as storage?

Comment: No its not a monolithic app.Its a website with database as neo4j.I have to decide language with gud framework which can help to build frontend and middleware

Comment: Then the language is irrelevant for communication and speed. You can focus on what you belive is best for front end development and communicate with Neo4J in Jason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My vote would be on Scala/Lift since they are a more natural fit for each other. I am not too familiar with the Jython/Django integration - but Django is written in pure Python so there might be overhead in interfacing between the two. With your Scala/Lift solution you use Scala for front and middle tier and it compiles down to Java byte code, which fits seamlessly with your neo4j database layer.

Comment: It does not fit "seamless with your neo4j database layer" as the front end is talking to the back end via a network protocoll. So basically the frontend technology is irrelevant. I would use what ever fits best to Neo4J. E.g. if you cn talk to Neo4J with Java RMI, you can "seamless" use Scala/Java/Lift. If Neo4J ofers Json then you can *easy* but not *seamless* use any other language/framework.

Comment: @Angel O'Sphere neo4j does provide Json but I dont know about RMI but if does what can be the best option now?
Edit: Neo4j does provide RMI

Comment: @Angel O'Sphere  What do u mean by frontend will talk to backend via network, dont we put database and the dynamic code there on the server only.
Sorry if am missing something obvious here but its my first time handling such a project

Comment: Neo4j is written in Java. His application is written in Java. Seems pretty seamless to me. Read more here http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.4.M04/apidocs/ and here http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Using_the_Neo4j_Server_with_Java.

Comment: @Perception Yes I know that, and if you would read this topic carefully you would know that I have asked him above whether he is working on a monolitic application or on a distributed one. He answered: it is a distributed one, a web application talkint to a Neo4J back and hence: it is not so seamless as it looks. @codecool: As you have checked for RMI I would suggest to go with RMI, it usually provides a quick and easy start up in development.

Comment: @Angel, quoted directly from OP's comment, which was a direct reply to you - 'I have to decide language with gud framework which can help to build frontend and MIDDLEWARE'. I emphasized the important part.

Comment: @Angel I think I did not understand your question about monolithic.
Neo4j provides embedded server so neo4j and scala code will be on same system.
In relational table based side,php actually provides us function calls which can edit the database and display results to webpage.
In my case php should call java functions like it call relational db functions.
But catch is in php I would have to use php/java bridge which is headache.
So I was considering sacala as it can seamlessly call those java functions.
Sorry for such a big reply but I was not making myself clear in less words :)

Comment: Hm, if you can use it "embedded" then it is "monolithic". Is that a commercial or hobby endeavor you are undertaking here? Sorry to ask so bluntly, but if you lack basic terminology to explain what you want to do and to talk about how to do it, I fear you wont be successful. If you can directly call the java methods of Neo4J without any network layer, then do as Perception suggests: go for Scala or Java. If you can't but have to go via some IP protocol with Jason as transport, then take the web programming environment you are most familiar with.

Comment: I know I lack the basic terminology but have to learn somewhere.Its more about learning than success and terminology :) If i learn here something good then it will definitely help me in this project and future ones too. I am going for commercial but it seems bigger than me so there is more opportunity to fail but also for more learning.
But thanks to stackoverflow and you people I have learnt a lot from here :)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the decompiled code of a Java and a Scala program calling method `method` on a class `X`, just instantiated:

```
public void callX();
  Code:
   0:   new #2; //class X
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method X."<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   aload_1
   9:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method X.method:()V
   12:  return

}

public void callX();
  Code:
   0:   new #7; //class X
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #11; //Method X."<init>":()V
   7:   astore_1
   8:   aload_1
   9:   invokevirtual   #14; //Method X.method:()V
   12:  return
```

I didn't even bother saying which one is which because, as you can see *there's absolutely no difference in how Scala and Java call Java code*. In fact, Java can call Scala code just as well, because it just doesn't know from bytecode that it was written in another language.

Comment: Seeing in believing is apt here I guess :)
If both compiles to same thing then how are so they so different and what scala gives that java cannot?

Comment: Scala compiles down to byte code, but the language syntax itself is significantly different from Java. In particular, Scala supports functional programming. In addition it has some other nice coding candy, like closures, domain specific languages and type value ranges. From a programmer point of view, it is possible to do some things in Scala that would be much harder to accomplish in Java, with fewer lines of code.

Comment: @codecool Bytecode is just a kind of machine code. Languages are created to _abstract_ over that, to provide a language capable of expressing high level concepts which can then be translated into that low level language. The same applies here -- Scala and Java translate into bytecode, but Scala provides higher levels of abstraction than Java.